# How to do partial update in fastapi?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I want to make "partial update" endpoint, but don't want to allow passing `null` in any field.

Here is the guide from fastapi https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-updates/#partial-updates-with-patch :

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str] = None
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: Optional[float] = None
    tax: float = 10.5
    tags: List[str] = []


@app.patch("/items/{item_id}", response_model=Item)
async def update_item(item_id: str, item: Item):
    ...
    update_data = item.dict(exclude_unset=True)
    ...
```

With this approach user can pass `{"name": null}` and corrupt database, because in my case `name` should always be a string.

So what should I do? The only approach I see so far is playing around with some sentinel objects (using them as "unset" marker instead of None), but this seems hacky and I doubt that pydantic will allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `exclude_none` in order to exclude values that are equal to `None`.

### Example

```
item.dict(exclude_none=True)
```

Source: [Pydantic docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#advanced-include-and-exclude)

Comment: But users should receive 400 if they pass non-string value for the field. But exclude_none can be useful, tnx

Comment: In fact, they should receive 400 in that case. Otherwise, you can use name: str = None and exclude it if None or raise 400 if not string